# File writing bugging

Tags: c, file

I'm working on a cipher project in C language. I must write 9 functions with multiple ciphering/deciphering purposes. This function is supposed to be able to read a text inside a 'message.txt' file, cipher/decipher the message (depending on user input) and then write the results in a new 'code.txt' file the function creates. The user will give a key (clef) and the mode (cipher/decipher) he wants and the function will execute based on another function which ciphers/deciphers following the Vigenère method. Here is my code, (some parts are in Spanish I'm sorry) first is the function which ciphers/deciphers, then the file reading/writing one and then the main(). (IF MODE==0 FUNCTION DECIPHERS).

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int vigenereCipher(char *chaine, char *key, char *code, int mode)
{
    int i = 0, c = 0;

    if (mode != 0) {
        for (; i < strlen(chaine); i++) {
            if (chaine[i] + key[c] < 256) {
                code[i] = chaine[i] + key[c];
                c += 1;
            } else {
                code[i] = chaine[i] + key[c] - 256;
                c += 1;
            }

            if (c == strlen(key)) {
                c = 0;
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (; i < strlen(chaine); i++) {
            if (chaine[i] - key[c] < 0) {
                code[i] = chaine[i] - key[c];
                c += 1;
            } else {
                code[i] = chaine[i] - key[c] + 256;
                c += 1;
            }

            if (c == strlen(key)) {
                c = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n %s -> %s \n", chaine, code);
    if (*chaine == *chaine) {
        printf("\n0\n");
    } else {
        printf("\n1\n");
    }
}

int encryptTextFile(char *key, int mode)
{
    char chaine[99999];
    char code[99999];
    int i;
    FILE *archivo1, *archivo2;

    archivo1 = fopen("message.txt", "r");
    archivo2 = fopen("code.txt", "w");

    fscanf(archivo1, "%s", chaine);

    vigenereCipher(chaine, key, code, mode);

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(chaine); i++) {
        fprintf(archivo2, "%c", code[i]);
    }

    fclose(archivo1);
    fclose(archivo2);
}

int main()
{
    char key[99999];
    int mode;

    printf("Enter encryption key: ");
    gets(key);

    printf("Enter desired mode (1 or 0): ");
    scanf("%i", &mode);

    encryptTextFile(key, mode);
}
```

This function can cipher/decipher correctly but when it tries to write the results in the 'code.txt' file it does not write the same ciphered/deciphered characters it gave before.

How can I correct this so it writes the same characters it changed into the 'code.txt' file?
Thank you. (Please let me know if you need something translated into English.)

Comment: In `chiffrementVigenere` where do you nul-terminate the strings you build?

Comment: Your code generates 6 compiler warnings from MSVC. Three concern signed/unsigned integer comparisons. One advises that `gets` is obsolete. Two advise that functions do not return any value when they should. Please enable all compiler warnings.

Comment: `Please enable all compiler warnings` and fix those problems before continuing

Comment: You don't check whether `fopen` and `fscanf` succeed. If they fail, you'll be working with garbage. Also `%s` in `fscanf` must have a limit on how much it will read, or better yet use `fgets`, else you're risking a buffer overflow. Similar problem with `gets`, use `fgets` instead. Making absurdly huge static buffers doesn't prevent that, 4096 should be the largest you need (the largest typical disk block).

Comment: Of course if you just read one character at a time, cyphered it, and wrote it out immediately, you would not have any worries about `fgets` or `fprints`.   Vigenere is not a block cypher but a character one. You might also look into the modulo operator `%` if you want to shorten your code

Comment: Since you are dealing in mod 256, theoretically you might encode a byte to zero, which would seem a string end to other parts of your program that expect C strings.  Not that you  would entering ASCII text with codes just below 256 anyway, but theoretically.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have solved these problems, and also the file writing bug.

Answer (score 0):

`strlen` uses the first `'\0'` to determine the length. So a cyphered string could be shortened erroneously by `strlen`.

So you need an other string representation, considering byte blocks with a size stored.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have solved these problems, and also the file writing bug.